# formulation of condition in if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have this:

```
$(function() {
    if () {
        $('#content').css('position', 'fixed');
    });
});
```

So, now what I want:
If the 'top' of '#content' is 0, I want the css that is written down in the function to happen. But I don't know how to write that down in between the brackets after 'if'.

Maybe someone can help me with this basic if-statement?

Much thanks in advance!

edit-----------------------------

Seems to work better and better, still one problem though.. I now have this:

```
$(function() {
    if ( $('#content').offset().top == 0) {
        $('#content').css({'position' : 'fixed'});
    }
    else {
        $('#content').css({'position' : 'relative'});
    }
});
```

And this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').scrollTop('100%');
});
```

But now the div is immediately 'fixed'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PjMcY/)

Use `$('selector').offset().top` to get the numeric value of the top position.

```
if ($('#content').offset().top == 0) {
    $('#content').css('position', 'fixed');
});
```

for more information you can see [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Also set your `css` in condition like this

```
$('#content').css({'position' : 'fixed'});
```

In case of your scroll to top you can do like this

```
$('#content').scrollTop(yourtopvalue); // your top value goes here.
```

For animated effects, you could do like this also

```
$('selector').animate({scrollTop:$('#content').offset().top}, 'slow');
```

You can mix up these stuffs like these ways using jQuery.

Comment: You mean instead of the if-statement?

Comment: Thanks! this part works now anyway.. Maybe you could help me out with an additional problem: How do I link the 'top' of my div to the scrolling? So that it knows when my div is scrolled to the top(top == 0)

Comment: @Luc See my answer to your additional problem. :) hope it helps!

Comment: You're helping me a lot, thanks! Still got some problems though... I edited my question to make it a little clearer!